What does も mean in this sentence?
This passage was taken from a membership announcement for a music producer's Youtube channel. At the end of some of his videos he says:

お集まりの皆様。LadyMonstersをご愛聴いただき、誠にありがとうございます。この度、我々の世界に、より深く浸かりたい「偏愛家」の皆様に、ぴったりな場を御用意いたしました。その名もスリラーサーカス。

The given translation was something like "Dear guests, we thank you very much for listening to LadyMonsters. Now, we've prepared a perfect place for freaks who wish to furher immerse themselves in our world. The name (of that place) is Thriller Circus But the も particle seems o be doing the opposite of what it's supposed to be doing. It's acting as a は or が particle. And this isn't the only place where I've seen も be used as a は or が. What's going on here?

In this case, the も works similarly to は, but it adds the nuance that not only the place itself impressive, but also its name is, too.
The も particle implies there is something else similar or related. Consider this example where there is a common theme of frequent actions of a person, so using も is correct:

彼は寝坊が多いし、遅刻も多い。 -- He oversleeps often, he is also late frequently.

Actually the も particle can be used even when something is not explicitly stated. For example:

彼は仕事ができないし、遅刻も多い。 -- He is an incapable worker as well as late often.

You might wonder why も is used in this example. The first part of the sentence "彼は仕事ができないし" talks about his poor performance, and the second part highlights another negative trait. Here, も fits better than は because it implies an additional negative aspect.
Similarly, the sentences in your question emphasize how impressive the place is. In this context, using も in the last sentence adds the nuance that not only the place is impressive, but its name too.

So using も instead of は would be like, instead of saying "we've prepared a place. The name is Thriller Circus", it'd be more like saying "we've prepared a place, AND the name is Thriller Circus". Is this correct?

The も is associating the two statements, while also emphasising that the sentiment expressed in the first statement is applicable to the second statement. The English example in your comment might be better expressed as "we've prepared the perfect place for you, AND the (perfect) name (for the place that we've prepared for you) is Thriller Circus!". The implication is that the audience will be excited by both the venue and the name of the venue, and the speaker is also trying to convey the fact that both aspects have been given equal attention.
